# Continuity of Kernel Mean Embeddings

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, machine-learning

Given some kernel $k: X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ with RKHS $H_k$ we say that $k$ is characteristic on the space of signed Radon measures over $X$, denoted by $\mathcal{M}(X)$, if the kernel mean embedding (KME) map is injective, i.e. the map
$$\mathcal{M}(X) \ni \mu \mapsto \int_X k(x,\cdot) \mu(dx) \in H_k$$
is one-to-one. The integral is to be seen in the Pettis sense.

Do we know anything about the continuity of the KME map? The topology usually considered on $\mathcal{M}(X)$ is the weak-$*$-topology. I have good reasons to believe that if $k(x,\cdot)$ is continuous and bounded, and $X$ is assumed to be a separable Banach space, then the KME map is continuous wrt the weak-$*$-topology. That said, I find the assumptions on $k$ too restrictive. Do you know anything about the continuity of kernel mean embeddings? Any insights/references are appreciated.